# cut mp4 file from 720*480 to 480*480

Tags: android, mp4, slice

I have recorded a mp4 file by my android application. Unfortunately,I want to cut it from 720*480 to 480*480, and delete the others. but I have no idea about it.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode it. Then crop the YUV frame to 480*480. Then encode again. But note that different phones have different encoders and decoders. And the YUV color formats can be different.

Comment: Oh,thanks.But How about the audio after decode and encode?...

Comment: In my case I needed to crop the video only. But I think you can use MediaMuxer to mux audio stream.

Comment: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#MediaMuxerTest demonstrates copying audio+video streams with MediaMuxer.  You'd need to tweak the video handling somewhat.